# Is there a problem with my map construction?

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, stdmap

My code didn't report a bug. But when run in the online judge system, I was told that it couldn't get right answer for some special samples. I can't figure it out, so I turn to here for help.

**Problem Description**

Every girl likes shopping,so does dandelion.Now she finds the shop is increasing the price every day because the Spring Festival is coming .She is fond of a shop which is called "memory". Now she wants to know the rank of this shop's price after the change of everyday.

**Input**

One line contians a number n ( n<=10000),stands for the number of shops.
Then n lines ,each line contains a string (the length is short than 31 and only contains lowercase letters and capital letters.)stands for the name of the shop.
Then a line contians a number m (1<=m<=50),stands for the days .
Then m parts , every parts contians n lines , each line contians a number s and a string p ,stands for this day ,the shop p 's price has increased s.

**Output**

Contains m lines ,In the ith line print a number of the shop "memory" 's rank after the ith day. We define the rank as :If there are t shops' price is higher than the "memory" , than its rank is t+1.

**Sample Input**

```
3
memory
kfc
wind
2
49 memory
49 kfc
48 wind
80 kfc
85 wind
83 memory
```

**Sample Output**

```
1
2
```

Code:

```
#include<algorithm>
#include<iostream>
#include<map>
#include<cstdio>
using namespace std;
const int maxn = 10010;

int main(){
    int n,m;
    map<string ,int> dic ;
    char names[maxn][32];
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(int i = 0;i<n;i++){
        scanf("%s",names[i]);
        dic[names[i]] = 0;
    }
    scanf("%d",&m);
    while(m--){
        for(int i = 0;i<n;i++){
            int temp;
            scanf("%d",&temp);
            char tp[32];
            scanf("%s",tp);
            dic[tp] += temp;
        }
        int ranking = 1;
        for(int j = 0;j<n;j++){
            if(dic[names[j]]>dic[names[0]]){
                ranking++;
            }
        }
        printf("%d\n",ranking);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Although I don't have any problem with the sample, but it Can't pass *black box* test.

Comment: Unrelated, but you don't need that array of arrays for the strings, just re-use one and the same array as you do later inside the n-loop. `std::string` (inside the map) will copy the value anyway.

Comment: Your code assumes that `memory` is the first shop. but nothing I can see in the problem description justifies that.

Comment: @john being faster, would have been my next comment. And then you might compare with dic["memory"] instead... Even better: Select that once before the loops, then you spare the multiple lookup: `auto& value = dic["memory"];` (but the reference is important!).

Comment: If using `scanf`, you should *always* check the return value (== number of correctly scanned values, i. e. 1 in your case). We *possibly* might assume that no invalid input will be provided, but getting used to good practice right from the start never hurts... (similarly: if you switch over to C++ streams, always check stream state after input operations).

Comment: @Aconcagua Yeah, never tried them myself but usually it seems that these online puzzles come down to finding a more efficient algorithm.

Comment: @john `std::unordered_map` might bring some improvement, especially if number of shops gets large. Having trouble of thinking about something more efficient (in thoughts played with list of shops sorted by price, but that can quickly get far worse, if shops overtake each other frequently...).

Comment: @john Typically the judge will say whether the program gave incorrect output or the program took too long based on its performance threshold. "couldn't get right answer for some special samples" sounds like this is an incorrect output case.